# React, Redux and Recompose: "dispatch is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, recompose

I've got a container/component (from `Redux` examples) complaining about "*dispatch is not a function*".  I had this working before I added `Recompose`.  I think `Recompose` puts a wrapper around `dispatch()`, so I need to expose it somehow.  Maybe `applyMiddleware` will do the trick, but I don't know where to hook it up?  What do I need to do?

**Container:**

```
const AddTodo = (props, dispatch) => {
  let input;
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        id="my-form-id"
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return;
          }
          dispatch(addTodo(input.value));//<<<OFFENDING LINE
          input.value = "";
        }}
      >
        <TextField
          id="agentName"
          label="Agent Name"
          placeholder="Placeholder"
          form="my-form-id"
          inputRef={el => (input = el)}
          className={classes.textField}
          margin="normal"
        />
        <Button variant="extendedFab" type="submit" className={classes.button}>
          <AddIcon className={classes.addIcon} />
          New Todo
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles),
  connect()
)(AddTodo);
```

**Root index.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./components/App";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: dispatch get's injected into props, try doing a `let {dispatch} = props`

Comment: @MoritzRoessler...So no applyMiddleware code?  Is what you suggest the generally accepted way to do this?  I'm trying to learn, not be difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two basic things to understand.

1.
When composing `connect()` Redux adds dispatch as a prop.

```
export default compose(
  withStyles(styles),
  connect() // <-- This adds dispatch to props.
)(AddTodo);
```

2.
You should access `props` as a single object or [destructure branches of the props object](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/).

This line is where the misunderstanding is happening.

```
const AddTodo = (props, dispatch) => { // <-- dispatch is not an parameter, it exists at props.dispatch
```

To fix things using your existing pattern do this.

```
const AddTodo = (props) => {
  let input;
  const { classes, dispatch } = props;
  return (
  ...
```

Optionally you can destructure the props parameter directly.

```
const AddTodo = ({ classes, dispatch }) => {
  let input;
  return (
  ...
```

With either approach the remaining code will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

connect passes the `dispatch` as a prop to the connected component, you should destructure it from the props.

```
const AddTodo = ({classes, dispatch}) => {
  let input;

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        id="my-form-id"
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return;
          }
          dispatch(addTodo(input.value));
          input.value = "";
        }}
      >
        <TextField
          id="agentName"
          label="Agent Name"
          placeholder="Placeholder"
          form="my-form-id"
          inputRef={el => (input = el)}
          className={classes.textField}
          margin="normal"
        />
        <Button variant="extendedFab" type="submit" className={classes.button}>
          <AddIcon className={classes.addIcon} />
          New Todo
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles),
  connect()
)(AddTodo);
```